# Rank and Total Number of players

Tags: ios, gamekit, leaderboard

I'm going to use iOS Leaderboard (GameCenter) to store the player scores.

In my game, I need to display the message like 'You are in TOP XX% players'. To do that I need to know the total number of players and the rank of current player.

1) Is there a way to calculate the rank of current player and the number of players without downloading all the scores?

2) Are there any limits for the maximum number of downloaded scores? For example, if I submit 1M scores, does it mean I can download all of them if I use default filters for range, timescope, players, etc.?